# #ifndef in c file?

Tags: c, header, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to put `#ifndef` at the top of a c file? Basically I need to check whether a certain preprocessor constant was declared when running the program and my program will change accordingly.

I need to check if `-D DESCENDING_ORDER=1` is added as an argument (doesn't matter what value given).

I have this code at the top of my main c file:

```
#ifndef DESCENDING_ORDER
int ascending = 1;
#else
int ascending = 0;
#endif
```

Works when compiling by itself, but I get errors when I try compiling with a Makefile, something along the lines of "expected identifier before 'int' for `int ascending = 1`.

Thanks.

EDIT - Added Makefile code

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-g -Wall
INC=-include
RES_OBS=res.o
LIBS=
all: res

res:    $(RES_OBS)

    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o res $(RES_OBS) $(LIBS) $(INC) res.h -D DESCENDING_ORDER=1

clean:
        rm -f *.o

clobber:
        make clean
        rm -f res
```

Kind of guessed and added `$(INC)....DESCENDING_ORDER=1` to the end of the command, so that's probably why it's not working. 
Command I'm using without makefile:

```
gcc res -include res.h -D DESCENDING_ORDER=1
```

EDIT 2 - Had a little play with different arguments and found that I get the same error if I remove `-include res.h` in the command. Still not sure how to correctly reference the header file in the makefile? I've added the `#include "res.h"` in my res.c file but still get the error.

Comment: It is possible and standard practice. You should show your `Makefile` rules. Perhaps using `remake -x` to debug your `Makefile` should help. Give exactly the source code and error messages.

Comment: Noted, added to post.

Comment: You should give much more details, e.g. the exact error message and the real `res.c` & `res.h` files.

Comment: The real files would be too big to post here, so I've just included where the error is pointing me to.
This is the error: `gcc -g -Wall -DDESCENDING_ORDER=1   -c -o res.o res.c.. res.c:10:1 error expected ';', identifier or '(' before 'int'.. make: *** [res.o] Error 1` and line 10 char 1 is where `int ascending = 0` is.

Comment: Probably the issue is just before that, in the preprocessed form. Maybe a missing semicolon or closing brace in some previously included file.

Comment: Definitely not, I can compile and run the code successfully using `gcc -g -Wall res.c -include res.h -DDESCENDING_ORDER=1; ./a.out`

Comment: What is the contents of res.h? This is most likely causing the problem.

Answer (score 3):

There is a typo in your `Makefile` since `$(CLAGS)` should be `$(CFLAGS)`.
 Learn a lot more about `make`, notably by running `make -p` which shows you the many built-in rules to `make` and use them (e.g. consider using `$(COMPILE.c)` and `$(LINK.c)` etc..)

Don't forget to add `-Wall` to your `CFLAGS`, because you want all the warnings from the compiler. You probably want debugging information too, so add `g` also.

On Linux, I do recommend using [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) for debugging `Makefile`-s by running `remake -x` which helps a lot.

Standard practices are:

- avoid passing `-include` to `gcc`, instead, add a`#include "res.h"` near the beginning of relevant `*.c` source files
- glue the `-D` to the defined symbol, e.g. `-DDESCENDING_ORDER=1`
- add in your `Makefile` the dependencies on relevant object files to the newly `#include`-d file `res.h`; notice that these dependencies could be automatically generated (by passing e.g. `-MD` to `gcc`, etc etc...)
- pass the `-DDESCENDING_ORDER=1`  thru `CFLAGS` or better `CPPFLAGS`

Don't forget that the order of program arguments to `gcc` matters a lot.

#### addenda

You may want to generate the preprocessed form `res.i` of your source code `res.c` using `gcc -C -E` and you could have a rule like

```
  res.i: res.c res.h
           $(CC) -C -E $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

then do `make res.i` and examine with some editor or pager (perhaps `less`) the preprocessor output `res.i` ; alternatively, do that on the command line

```
  gcc -C -E -I. -DDESCENDING_ORDER=1  res.c | less
```

you could remove the generated line information and do

```
  gcc -C -E -I. -DDESCENDING_ORDER=1  res.c | grep -v '^#' > res_.i
  gcc -Wall -c res_.i
```

The point is that the preprocessing in *C* is a textual operation, and your preprocessed form is wrong.

BTW very recent Clang/LLVM (version 3.2) or GCC (just released version 4.8) compilers give you much better messages regarding preprocessing.

Comment: Thanks Basile. I definitely have `CFLAGS` instead of `CLAGS`, must have copied it over and accidently deleted the letter. I've removed `-include` and added `#include "result.h"` in my code and added `-DDESCENDING_ORDER=1` to `CFLAGS` but I'm still receiving the error!

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine. The error you're getting when using a Makefile has to do with something else (it's hard to be sure without seeing what comes before the `#ifndef` and seeing the Makefile).