# Is it necessary to write #include< stdio.h> in every function in a separate file? C

Tags: c

I have started to learn C recently. I am using Eclipse and I want to create a program where each function is in a different file. My question is the following:

This in my main.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "header.h"

int main(void) {
    function();
    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My header.h:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_
#define HEADER_H_

void function (void);

#endif /* HEADER_H_ */
```

And my function.c:

```
#include <stdio.h> //Necessary??

void function (void){
    printf("Hello\n");
}
```

Is it necessary to write #include< stdio.h>, #include< stdlib.h>, etc. in every function? The program works without #include  in function.c but I get a warning.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can not add them and just compile and see where they are missing and add them where they should be

Comment: Why do you want to have each function in a different file? My feeling is that it is a very bad habit (but you could do that if you really wanted to).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Maybe I am wrong because I am new in this. But I think that having one or just a few functions per source file the program looks tidier and also it is faster to find the part that you want to edit (less time scrolling...). Thanks a lot for your previous answer, very complete

Comment: Look at existing practice (free software written in C). You'll find many files of many thousand lines containing many dozen of functions. But this is a matter of habits. You could write a program with thousand of short files of a few dozen lines each (but it will compile slower) and only one function definition per file.

Comment: BTW, Eclipse is rumored to be not very good for writing C code. Did you consider switching to a more powerful source code editor (e.g. some recent `emacs` or `vim` with suitable extensions) ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I will follow your advice and I will read some existing code. I think it is a good idea for learning how to organise a programme. About Eclipse, it seems to work ok for what I am doing now. As I am a beginner I don't think it is so important to use the most powerful or the most efficient code editor. But thanks a lot for your advices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read more about the [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) (and also [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor)). You often (and *conventionally*, so it is more a good *habit* than a requirement) would add a `#include <stdio.h>` preprocessor [include directive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive) near the start of your translation unit (or near the start of your header file), i.e. your `*.c` source file. Of course you need to include `<stdio.h>` only in translation units using some standard I/O function (or name of a type like `FILE`, or variable like `stdout`). So you can avoid `<stdio.h>` in modules unrelated to I/O, such as code doing only computations.

You certainly don't need to define one function per source file. It is common (and I even recommend it) to define several functions in one source file. In particular, you could declare `static` some *internal* function and call it from another one (in the same [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit)).

You might want, with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), to have a single [pre-compiled header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12438040/841108) (which practically has to include other ones), and you could decide to put all standard headers inclusions inside your `header.h`. Read about [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

You could want to *define* (not only declare) some short `static inline` functions in your `header.h`, hoping that the compiler would [inline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) most calls to them.

Your `function.c` practically needs to `#include <stdio.h>`  because it is using `printf`. If you miss that include you need to *properly* declare `printf`.

BTW, if you compile with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), don't forget to enable all warnings & debug info, using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. And try once to get the preprocessed form using `gcc -C -E function.c > function.i` then look with a [pager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_pager) (or an editor) into the generated `function.i`. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15584711/841108).

Notice that Eclipse is *not a [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler)* but an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), that is a glorified [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) able to run other programs (like compilers, debuggers, etc...). Your compiler -started by Eclipse- is likely to be GCC (or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/)).

Read also the [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) book.

NB. Programming in C requires to define and follow many conventions, which could vary from one project to the next. But you'll better explicit them. I recommend to study the source code of some small or medium sized [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) project (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/)).

Answer (score 4):

You only include the appropriate headers for those functions that are declared in  that header that you are using.

In your example, `main.c` - You do not need to include `#include <stdio.h>`. However in `function.c` you do need to include it (stdio.h). This is because you are using the function `printf` in the code.